# MS Word VBA Parsing string in a function as Object name

Tags: vba, string, function, ms-word, label

I a am newbee in VBA programming. I want to adapt a dotm document with functions.
I have a dropdown "Res_i" and label: "Lb_Date_i", all as ActiveX, where i goes from 1 to 10.
I want to set the caption of label in depending of options of the dropdown menu.

This my function, declared in Modules

```
Public Function T_Date(ByRef dt As Object, p As Integer)
'p=0, release the date to 01.01.1900
'p=1, for user selected date
'p=2, for the date of today

Select Case p
    Case "0"
        With dt
            .Caption = VBA.Format("01.01.2000", "dd.mm.yyyy")
        End With
    Case "1"
        With dt
        .Caption = VBA.Format(TestDate, "dd.mm.yyyy")
        End With
    Case "2"
        With dt
        .Caption = VBA.Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy")
        End With
End Select

End Function
```

And the Sub:

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal CCtrl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
With ActiveDocument
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 10

If (CCtrl.Title = "Res_" & i) Then
    Dim d_Title As String
    d_Title = "Lb_Date_" & i
End If

With CCtrl
Select Case .Range
    Case "Choose a test result."
            .Range.Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = wdRed
            .Range.Font.ColorIndex = wdWhite
            Call T_Date(d_Title, 0)
    Case "PASS"
            .Range.Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = wdWhite
            .Range.Font.ColorIndex = wdGreen
            ActiveDocument.Lb_Date_1.Caption = " by Engineer: "
                           
End Select

End With
Next
End With
End Sub
```

Both are in short Version here.

`ActiveDocument.Lb_Date_1.Caption = " by Engineer: "`
works fine, also

```
Call T_Date(Lb_Date_1, 0)
```

but
`Call T_Date(d_Title, 0)` it does not work

How can I parse d_Title as Label name in a function?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Integers are numbers so they should not be wrapped in `" "` quotes. Remove the quotes in the select statement.

Comment: Thank you Kosta. I switched from int to long and I removed quotes. But that does not help me to parse a string as Label name.

Comment: For a date value, use `#01.01.2000#`. Enclosing the value in `#` forces VBA to interpret that value as a date-time.

Comment: Your question says that you have dropdowns and labels as ActiveX, but your code is for Content Controls. So which do you have? Your question can’t be answered unless you provide full and correct information.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple of examples of how you can access a control using its name:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim lbl As Object
    
    'method 1: CallByName
    Set lbl = CallByName(ActiveDocument, "Label1", VbGet)
    lbl.Caption = "hello"
    
    'method 2: use a function
    Set lbl = ControlByName(ActiveDocument, "Label1")
    lbl.Caption = "hello again"
    

End Sub

'Return an ActiveX control named `nm` from document `doc`
'  Returns Nothing if no match
Function ControlByName(doc As Document, nm As String) As Object
    Dim shp
    For Each shp In doc.InlineShapes
        If Not shp.OLEFormat Is Nothing Then
            If shp.OLEFormat.Object.Name = nm Then
                Set ControlByName = shp.OLEFormat.Object
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next shp
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you Tim! It works like a charm! I used method1.